# Moving div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi this is my first post. I am designing a game with javascript and jquery and I currently have a div that represents the player and I can't figure out how to make the character move
I currently just have the div 
`<div id="player"></div>`
I would prefer to use jquery for this but I am willing to use regular javascript too.

Edit: I need to move the div using the arrow keys.

Comment: Please show what have you tried.

Comment: First understand that when your using jquery, you're using javascript second, read the docs which provide examples on how you can move a div http://api.jquery.com/animate/, and third this question should by close

Comment: How do you want it to move, by dragging or moving random direction distance..etc?

Answer (score 1):

Well you will require a hell lot of code in jQuery, I would prefer you to use some other languages that are basically meant to be for the Gaming Development.

However, you can try this:

```
div {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

This will set a margin of 100px for the div.

```
$('#player').hover(function () {
 $(this).css('margin-left', '200px');
});
```

This will move the div to a more 100px from the left. You can use `animate` to animate this or slow this process down, so that it will look like he is moving. This way, you will get a chance to change the image in a way that it will look like he is moving his body (arm, leg etc).

Then to make him jump use:

```
$('#player').click(function () {
  $(this).css('margin-bottom', '50px');
});
```

But that won't work pretty cool. As only the image will move not animate itself like moving its body parts too.

I guess `animate` will be basic and necessary tool for the game development in jQuery, as this will let you create functions at time intervals where you can change the images so that the player will look like locomoting as well as moving, and not just locomoting from one place to the other.

Using regular JS will require even more code than jQuery would. So you keep running jQuery.

Here is a plugin that you might want to check!

http://gamequeryjs.com/ Its jQuery as you said you want to stick with the jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using JQuery `.animate()`

> Description: Perform a custom animation of a set of CSS properties

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LWAkr/)
example code

```
 $( "#player" ).click(function(){
      $( this ).animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
 });
```

[.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: I found a demo of what I was looking for at http://jsfiddle.net/bDMnX/7/ but thanks for your posts anyways.